# drilling a heatsink for a hot silicon diode?

Tags: diodes, heatsink

I had to adjust a CC/CV charger by 0.5-0.8 volts. The charger is rated at 3.5 Amps 58.8V, and I have some 50-100V diodes rated at 5A ( 6A10 MIC ).

The diode gets to about 100'C which is a bit on the hot side to ensure longevity and reliability. I'm thinking of making a small heatsink from aluminium for it.

If i put two diodes in parallel inside one small heatsink, would it be better than 1 diode in the same sized heatsink, and would it provide redundancy, seeing as it's only for a voltage drop?

Comment: The real question is: what is the application that requires a voltage adjustment of barely 1%? If you provide more information, we may be able to eliminate the need for the diode.

Comment: I bought an SLA charger which was supposed to be 58.8V and which seems to be 59.2 on my multimeter, by mistake from within a list of Lithium 58.8V chargers, it's definitely .5V too high. I also bought a Lithium charger, which is 58.8V, but it has an auto switch off function which i think is preventing the cell groups from balancing, they finished at 4.1/4.2 volts randomly. So i need to do some testing with the CC/CV SLA charger at 58.4volts roundabout until i buy a new charger.

Comment: I still think you are chasing windmills. What is the voltage tolerance on these chargers? How accurate is your multimeter? What are you charging? How are your cell groups connected? I can't believe that the charging requirements are so precise that less then 1 volt out of 58 will make any difference.

Comment: I've already charged it half up with a charger at the perfect voltage, after 1 hour the diode was too hot that's all. It's Lithium, It's charging to a BMS. of course Lithium requires very precise voltages. I expect the BMS is designed with that in mind and is very finely tuned to refuse over-voltage from the charger, I rather use the correct voltage than fry the cuircuitboard, it has very small fine tune chips on it made for a specific charger.

Comment: SLA chargers behave differently than lion chargers, they are NOT interchangeable, even if the voltage is "close" to what you expect. an SLA charger won't have the proper charging mode and cycles, aka a potentially dangerous situation.

Comment: it's a CC/CV current voltage type, the most simple.

Comment: Lithium ion chargers differ from lead acid chargers in that the lithium ion chargers will detect end of charge and stop charging. Lead acid chargers may or may not detect end of charge, but whether they do or not, they apply a float voltage for maintenance after end of charge. It is considered unsafe to float charge lithium ion batteries. It may be less dangerous if you float them at 4.1V / cell, but still cannot be considered a best practice. So, all this is a long way of saying that it is not really a great idea to charge your lithium ion batteries with a lead acid charger.

Comment: More to your question. If you change the current in your diode (by adding two in parallel) you will change the forward voltage a bit. Forward voltage will tend to decrease, all else being equal. If you change the temperature of your diode (by adding a heatsink), you will also change the forward voltage a bit. Voltage will increase if temperature is lower (forward voltage has a negative temperature coefficient).

Comment: I guess you have a 14S pack. 59.2V works out to 4.23V per cell. I agree with @Barry.

Comment: Hi, I think i have a good compromise. 59.2v could overheat a BMS with balancing function, fortunately i have only a limiting BMS... If you charge the cells to 4.1, you have 800 cycles from them, they barely age for 4-5 years... So I will make a switch-box with undervolt/standard option so that I only recharge them all to 4.2V every dozen cycles for balancing, and otherwise i will keep them in the 4.1Range. I'll use 2 diodes in series to achieve the undervolt. for 400 dollars of cells, it makes sense to undervolt them a bit to 4.1v

Comment: For 400 dollars of cells, it makes sense to get a high quality charger that supports LiIon correctly and allows you to set the exact end-of-charge voltage you want. However, I agree with your idea of only charging to 4.1.